# Clicking on a point in map giving wrong latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a simple polyline in google maps. I have also added click event listener to the polyline.

The problem is when i click on the line it gives a latitude and longitude coordinate somewhere in Canada even though the polyline is in US.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
      // the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
      // Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 30,
          center: {lat: 38.582692796303924, lng: -89.9953046014092},
          mapTypeId: 'satellite'
        });



          var flightPlanCoordinates = [
              {lat: 38.582692796303924, lng: -89.9953046014092},
              {lat: 38.582663144388235, lng: -89.99447848103262}
            ];

           var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    icons: [{icon: {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW}, offset: '100%'}],
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: 'red',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                 });

            flightPath.setMap(map);


              google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {

                         var arr = this.getPath();
                         //coordinates of start and end path points
                         console.log(arr.getAt(0).lat() + ', ' + arr.getAt(0).lng());
                         console.log(arr.getAt(1).lat() + ', ' + arr.getAt(1).lng());

                         //coordinates of clicked point
                         console.log(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());

            });



        flightPath.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=validkey&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please follow these steps to reproduce the problem.

```
1) First save the above code in html file and replace validkey to a valid google maps api key. 
2) When the map displays it should already be at maximum zoom level and in satellite mode. 
3) Now click F12 to open developer tools console. 
4) Click on somewhere between the polyline. 
5) It prints three lines.
```

[image]

You can see that the last line should be the coordinate of the clicked point. The latitude and longitude it gives is somewhere in Canada.

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: this is a weird one! - seems perfectly fine for a location I chose in scotland but the above does indeed throw a peculiar error....

Comment: thanks for validating.

Comment: This is not a solution, obviously, but this seems to only happen when the map is tilted (add `tilt: 0` in your map options or do a `map.setTilt(0)`). Your zoom level also is out of range (max zoom level in this area is 20) but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the issue.

Comment: Another hint: this happens in both the release and experimental versions of the API but works fine with 3.31. So this *looks like* a newly introduced bug. (Oh and clicking on the map itself returns the correct coordinates).

Comment: You beat me to it @MrUpsidown, done a few further tests and tried `tilt(0)` etc and agree with your comments

Comment: I have created [a new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110797001). Hopefully this will get fixed in the next release. For the time being, you can use `v=3.31` in your API call and you should be fine.

Comment: Apparently someone was quicker than me and had already created an issue but didn't report here, so you can [find it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110796548).

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue.  Here is my work around...

I have an infowindow that I want to appear right where I click the polyline.  Works fine in aerial view, but when testing in a tilted(3d) view it was getting the wrong coordinates.  I was using event.latLng on the listener for the polyline click. So what I did was overwrite that latLng when tilted with a middle point in the path of the polyline.

Code Before :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function(event) { 
   openInfoWindow(event.latLng, infoWindowPolyline);
});
```

Code After :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function(event) { 
   latLng = ((map.getTilt() == 0) ? event.latLng : getMiddlePoint(polyline.getPath()) );
   openInfoWindow(latLng, infoWindowPolyline);
});

function getMiddlePoint(pathArr) {
   pathLength = pathArr.length;

   if (pathLength <= 2) {
       index = 1;
   } else {
       index = Math.ceil(pathArr.length / 2);
   }
   myLatlng = { lat: pathArr.getAt(index).lat(), lng: pathArr.getAt(index).lng() };
   return myLatlng;
}
```